# Load Inner Class Java

Tags: java, eclipse, inner-classes

I have this class in Java (it's from JaCoCo Project):

```
public class MemoryMultiReportOutput implements IMultiReportOutput {

    private final Map<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> files = new HashMap<String, ByteArrayOutputStream>();

    private final Set<String> open = new HashSet<String>();

    private boolean closed = false;

    public OutputStream createFile(final String path) throws IOException {
        assertFalse("Duplicate output " + path, files.containsKey(path));
        open.add(path);
        final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                open.remove(path);
                super.close();
            }
        };
        files.put(path, out);
        return out;
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        closed = true;
    }

    public void assertEmpty() {
        assertEquals(Collections.emptySet(), files.keySet());
    }

    public void assertFile(String path) {
        assertNotNull(String.format("Missing file %s. Actual files are %s.",
                path, files.keySet()), files.get(path));
    }

    public void assertSingleFile(String path) {
        assertEquals(Collections.singleton(path), files.keySet());
    }

    public byte[] getFile(String path) {
        assertFile(path);
        return files.get(path).toByteArray();
    }

    public InputStream getFileAsStream(String path) {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(getFile(path));
    }

    public void assertAllClosed() {
        assertEquals(Collections.emptySet(), open);
        assertTrue(closed);
    }
}
```

When I compile this class the Eclipse create `MemoryMultiReportOutput.class` and `MemoryMultiReportOutput$1.class`.

First question: Why Eclipse create the `MemoryMultiReportOutput$1.class`? Eclipse considers the `ByteArrayOutputStream out` a InnerClass?

But my problem is, when I load the `MemoryMultiReportOutput.class` how can I load the all innerclasses present in parent class?

Comment: For what purpose are you worried about loading the inner class? Are you writing a class loader?

Comment: I have a JUnit Test that invoke this class and If I haven't the MemoryMultiReportOutput.class and MemoryMultiReportOutput$1.class loaded, the result of JUnitCore.run(...) is ClassNotFound...
Yes, I have this [ClassLoader](http://pastebin.com/TjmLr702)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            open.remove(path);
            super.close();
        }
    };
```

Here you are creating a subclass of the ByteArrayOutputStream on the fly, i.e anonymous. This is why you have another .class file.

To answer your second question:

You can only load parent inner classes, visible to the subclass, through the Superclass's instance object :

```
Superclass s = new Superclass();
Superclass.Subclass sub = s.new Subclass();
```

If the inner class is static i.e a **top-level nested class** (since there is no such thing as inner static class) can be instantiated like this:

```
Superclass.Subclass s = new Superclass.Subclass();
```

and it does not require an object instance of the superclass.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your creating an anonymous inner class with the

```
new ByteArrayOutputStream()
```

That's why you see the `MemoryMultiReportOutput$1.class` file.

You don't need to do anything to load the inner classes. That will happen automatically.

If your asking how to access the inner class from another class that's a bit different. You would need to mark it `public` or provide an accessor that would return an instance of the class. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: To run JUnitCore.run(...) I need the MemoryMultiReportOutput.class and MemoryMultiReportOutput$1.class loaded... I have this [ClassLoader](http://pastebin.com/TjmLr702) to load Classes, but it only load the MemoryMultiReportOutput.class and not the anonymous inner class.